# How I use .htaccess to change a tag driection?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I used .htaccess to change my url from

http://example.com/profile.php?user_id=115451

to

http://example.com/profile/115451

This is my .htaccess it work for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But in my profile.php have a tag like this

```
<a href='./'>Home</a>
```

When I click this link it should goto http://example.com/ but it goto http://example.com/profile/

Same problem with img tag, image on http://example.com/profile/115451 can not load,

But on http://example.com/profile.php?user_id=115451 it's no problem.

Comment: `./` means "the root of the current directory". Since your URL's in the `/profile/` directory (even if one doesn't actually exist on the file system), it's doing exactly what it's supposed to. It's generally a bad idea to use URLs like `./` and `../`, as they break if you change the structure.

Comment: Thank you, But I has a problem with another a tag.
I have <a href='newArticle.php'>Create</a> when click on http://example.com/profile.php?user_id=115451 it go to http://example.com/newArticle.php, But on http://example.com/profile/115451 it go to http://example.com/profile/newArticle.php

Comment: profile.php is on root directory.

Comment: Yes, that's for the same reason. You need `<a href="/newArticle.php">` or it'll look in the current directory, which is `/profile/`.

Comment: Oh, Thank! now I've solved the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is exactly that:

```
<a href='/'>Home</a>
```

Nothing to change in .htaccess